# reading info using scanner from text file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am facing this problem reading info from file. So i have this text file with integers that I want to read and add into my ArrayList. My problem now is that scanner only seems to read the first 2 lines instead of the entire file.

My Text file:

```
6
0 4 10 0 0 2
4 0 5 0 0 7
10 5 0 4 0 0
0 0 4 0 3 8
0 0 0 3 0 6
2 7 0 8 6 0
2 5
```

And this is my code:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputFileName);
Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);

// read in the data here
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    if(in.hasNextInt())
        alist.add(in.nextInt());
    in.nextLine();
}
```

This is my output:
`6 0 4 10 0 0 2 2`

Hopefully somebody can me out with this. I tried storing everything in string and reading from there but i ended up with everything in single digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this to read all the integers

```
while(in.hasNextInt()){
    alist.add(in.nextInt());
}
```

When you say `in.nextLine();` in your code it will get a new line. So in the next iteration it will only scan the first integer in the line. But with `hasNextInt` `nextInt` pair it will get integers skipping whitespace (space and new lines) and stop when it reaches the end of file

Comment: I can't believe how dumb I sound asking this question. But thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you're reading the first integer of each line, because you are looping on lines but not on their content : you just check if the first token on the line is an int, read it, and go on to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputFileName);
Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);

// read in the data here
while(in.hasNext()){
    alist.add(in.nextInt());
}
```

You were having issue because of `in.nextLine();` that you called in the end of the while loop. This will call in the next line, which make you skip lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(in.hasNextInt())
    alist.add(in.nextInt());
```

Replace with

```
while(in.hasNextInt())
{
    alist.add(in.nextInt());
}
```

Because you read int from each line only once.